# This custom Wordpress Editor block is not showing up, neither are the console logs

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin, that currently has three very simple tasks: add three blocks to the editor. One to easily add an H3 title, one to add an intro and the last one is stumping me.

The block is an information block for reviewing boardgames. I want to be able to toggle all the stats on and off individually in the sidebar by checkbox. If I enable it, I want to display the stat in the editor, and allow the author of the article to add a value to it.

This should result in a div on the frontend with an  to show all the enabled stats and their value.

**The main problem:** The block does not show up in the editor, even though the other two blocks are showing up perfectly fine.

I've added console logs because the block was not showing up. I am, however, not seeing any console logs at all. The other two blocks are still showing up fine.

I've tried pure JSX before, that usually does not work but I thought it was worth a try. Now I've reverted it back to using createElement instead.

**I've included the full code here. I suspect the issue comes from the section: ================ Boardgame Infoblock ================**

Thanks in advance for helping out!

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { InspectorControls, PanelBody, ToggleControl, TextControl, RangeControl } = wp.editor;

// ================ Tussenkop ================

wp.blocks.registerBlockType('bordspellencafeplugin/tussenkop', {
    title: 'Tussenkop', // De titel van je blok
    icon: 'heading', // Het pictogram van je blok (kies een geschikte uit de Dashicons: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/)
    category: 'common', // De categorie waarin je blok wordt weergegeven

    // De bewerkingsinterface voor je blok
    edit: function(props) {
        // Functie om de inhoud van het blok bij te werken
        function updateContent(content) {
            props.setAttributes({ content });
        }

        return wp.element.createElement(
            'div',
            null,
            wp.element.createElement(
                'h3',
                null,
                wp.element.createElement(
                    wp.editor.RichText,
                    {
                        tagName: 'span', // Gebruik een span-tag om een inline element te maken
                        value: props.attributes.content,
                        onChange: updateContent,
                        placeholder: 'Schrijf hier een pakkende tussenkop...'
                    }
                )
            )
        );
    },

    // De weergave van je blok op de frontend
    save: function(props) {
        return wp.element.createElement('h3', null, props.attributes.content);
    },
});

// ================ Intro ================

wp.blocks.registerBlockType('bordspellencafeplugin/intro', {
    title: 'Intro', // De titel van je blok
    icon: 'text', // Het pictogram van je blok (kies een geschikte uit de Dashicons: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/)
    category: 'common', // De categorie waarin je blok wordt weergegeven

    // De bewerkingsinterface voor je blok
    edit: function(props) {
        // Functie om de inhoud van het blok bij te werken
        function updateContent(content) {
            props.setAttributes({ content });
        }

        return wp.element.createElement(
            'div',
            null,
            wp.element.createElement(
                'b',
                null,
                wp.element.createElement(
                    wp.editor.RichText,
                    {
                        tagName: 'span', // Gebruik een span-tag om een inline element te maken
                        value: props.attributes.content,
                        onChange: updateContent,
                        placeholder: 'Schrijf hier je intro. Gebruik maximaal 4 zinnen.'
                    }
                )
            )
        );
    },

    // De weergave van je blok op de frontend
    save: function(props) {
        return wp.element.createElement('b', null, props.attributes.content);
    },
});

// ================ Boardgame Infoblock ================

wp.blocks.registerBlockType('bordspellencafeplugin/bordspelinfo', {
    
    title: 'Bordspelinfo',
    icon: 'block',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        showName: { type: 'boolean', default: true },
        showPublisher: { type: 'boolean', default: true },
        showPlayers: { type: 'boolean', default: true },
        showPlaytime: { type: 'boolean', default: true },
        showPrice: { type: 'boolean', default: true },
        showGrade: { type: 'boolean', default: true },
        name: { type: 'string', default: '' },
        publisherName: { type: 'string', default: '' },
        publisherLink: { type: 'string', default: '' },
        players: { type: 'string', default: '' },
        playtime: { type: 'string', default: '' },
        price: { type: 'string', default: '' },
        grade: { type: 'number', default: 0 },
    },

    edit: function (props) {
        const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
        console.log('Boardgame info block is being edited.');
        return wp.element.createElement(
            'div',
            null,
            wp.element.createElement(
                InspectorControls,
                null,
                wp.element.createElement(
                    PanelBody,
                    { title: 'Boardspel info' },
                    wp.element.createElement(ToggleControl, {
                        label: 'Show Name',
                        checked: attributes.showName,
                        onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ showName: value }),
                    }),
                    wp.element.createElement(ToggleControl, {
                        label: 'Show Publisher',
                        checked: attributes.showPublisher,
                        onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ showPublisher: value }),
                    }),
                    wp.element.createElement(ToggleControl, {
                        label: 'Show Players',
                        checked: attributes.showPlayers,
                        onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ showPlayers: value }),
                    }),
                    wp.element.createElement(ToggleControl, {
                        label: 'Show Playtime',
                        checked: attributes.showPlaytime,
                        onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ showPlaytime: value }),
                    }),
                    wp.element.createElement(ToggleControl, {
                        label: 'Show Price',
                        checked: attributes.showPrice,
                        onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ showPrice: value }),
                    }),
                    wp.element.createElement(ToggleControl, {
                        label: 'Show Grade',
                        checked: attributes.showGrade,
                        onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ showGrade: value }),
                    })
                )
            ),
            attributes.showName && wp.element.createElement(TextControl, {
                label: 'Board Game Name',
                value: attributes.name,
                onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ name: value }),
            }),
            attributes.showPublisher && wp.element.createElement(
                'div',
                null,
                wp.element.createElement(TextControl, {
                    label: 'Publisher Name',
                    value: attributes.publisherName,
                    onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ publisherName: value }),
                }),
                wp.element.createElement(TextControl, {
                    label: 'Publisher Link',
                    value: attributes.publisherLink,
                    onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ publisherLink: value }),
                })
            ),
            attributes.showPlayers && wp.element.createElement(TextControl, {
                label: 'Number of Players',
                value: attributes.players,
                onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ players: value }),
            }),
            attributes.showPlaytime && wp.element.createElement(TextControl, {
                label: 'Playtime',
                value: attributes.playtime,
                onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ playtime: value }),
            }),
            attributes.showPrice && wp.element.createElement(TextControl, {
                label: 'Average Price',
                value: attributes.price,
                onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ price: value }),
            }),
            attributes.showGrade && wp.element.createElement(RangeControl, {
                label: 'Grade (1.0 - 10.0)',
                value: attributes.grade,
                onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ grade: value }),
                min: 1,
                max: 10,
                step: 0.1,
            })
        );
    },
    

    save: function (props) {
        console.log('Saving bordspelinfo block');
        return wp.element.createElement(
            'div',
            { style: { background: '#f0f0f0', borderRadius: '5px', padding: '10px' } },
            wp.element.createElement(
                'ul',
                null,
                props.attributes.showName && wp.element.createElement('li', null, wp.element.createElement('strong', null, 'Name:'), ' ', props.attributes.name),
                props.attributes.showPublisher && wp.element.createElement('li', null,
                    wp.element.createElement('strong', null, 'Publisher:'),
                    ' ',
                    props.attributes.publisherLink ? (
                        wp.element.createElement('a', { href: props.attributes.publisherLink, target: '_blank', rel: 'noopener noreferrer' }, props.attributes.publisherName)
                    ) : (
                        props.attributes.publisherName
                    )
                ),
                props.attributes.showPlayers && wp.element.createElement('li', null, wp.element.createElement('strong', null, 'Players:'), ' ', props.attributes.players),
                props.attributes.showPlaytime && wp.element.createElement('li', null, wp.element.createElement('strong', null, 'Playtime:'), ' ', props.attributes.playtime),
                props.attributes.showPrice && wp.element.createElement('li', null, wp.element.createElement('strong', null, 'Average Price:'), ' ', props.attributes.price),
                props.attributes.showGrade && wp.element.createElement('li', null, wp.element.createElement('strong', null, 'Grade:'), ' ', props.attributes.grade)
            )
        );
    },
});
```